# How many URLs can be written to a Physical Web Beacon?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon-android, beacon, eddystone-url

I am trying to understand the **Physical Web Beacon** over **Normal Beacons**. As normal beacons will advertise only Manufacture Id , Certain Services and Characteristics UUIDs but the Physical Web Beacon can advertise URLs.

So , i want to understand , how many URLs we can write to a Physical Web Beacon and also is the writing URLs will be done by Manufacturer or can also be done by developer too?

How much memory a Physical Web Beacon has to store a iBeacon or Eddystone format URLs?

Also is [this](https://store.gimbal.com/collections/beacons/products/s10) Beacon **Eddystone Physical Web Beacon**?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Eddystone-URL format allows transmitting only a single compressed URL** in a Bluetooth LE advertisement.  That said, it is theoretically possible to make a beacon transmit more than one URL by "interleaving" multiple advertisements with different URLs from the same beacon.  While I am unaware of any commercial products supporting Eddystone-URL that allow this, you could always build your own.

Writing a URL to a beacon is typically done by the developer or beacon owner at beacon configuration time.  The way you do this is different for each beacon manufacturer.

Similarly, the amount of memory available for identifier storage is manufacturer-specific, so the answer varies by beacon model. Radius Networks' RadBeacon USB, for example, allows configuring up to four different beacon types to be advertised, each with its own identifiers.

Full disclosure: I work for Radius Networks.

Comment: Thank you so much for the brief. Now i got the idea about Eddystone-URL

Comment: Can you please tell me about this beacon , is it a Eddystone beacon :  https://store.gimbal.com/collections/beacons/products/s10  and will it work as a physical web beacon. please let me know

Comment: Sorry, I don't work for Gimbal so I don't have additional details about their products.  You may try contacting them through their website and asking there.

Comment: yes sure i understand , but i have already submitted the post to their forum but no answer :(